# linux + what the best way to merge files

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, ksh

I have the following files ( more then 80 files ) under /var/tmp  directory

```
 report1.txt
 report2.txt
 report3.txt
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
```

What the best way to merge all the files: **report[1-N].txt** to one single file

For now I do the following steps in order to merge all files to one file ( but this way isn’t elegant way .. )

```
cat report1.txt >> report2.txt
cat report2.txt >> report3.txt
.
.
.
 .
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html):

```
cat report{1..80} > allreports.txt
```

---

EDIT: As per your comments, you want to use a variable.  Since brace expansion happens before variable expansion, you cannot use a variable within braces.  An alternative would be to make use of `seq` with a custom format:

```
cat $(seq -f "report%g.txt" $NUM) > allreports.txt
```

where `NUM` is the variable that you want to pass.  By default, the sequence would start from 1.  If you want to alter that, specify both the first and last numbers (or variables):

```
cat $(seq -f "report%g.txt" $start $end) > allreports.txt
```

Comment: nice solution -:) +1 for you

Comment: But if I cant to verify the total number of the files , then what is your solution? ( 80 can be other number ) , can I set some VAL in place 80 that count all the files?

Comment: @maihabunash No, brace expansion happens before variable expansion.  As such, you cannot use a variable with `{..}`.  A way might be to make use of globs, but that would not guarantee the order to be preserved.  As such, you'd a loop in that case.

Comment: yes you right - but I have still the problem that I cant verify what is the last number and this number can change evry time ( depend how many files we have ) -:(

Answer (score 1):

You can use `*`

```
cat report* > newfile
```

It will take all files starting with  `report` and put them to one new file

Comment: but if I have also file as report@.txt , we only want to merge file that have this rule - report1-N.txt  ( while N is integer number

Comment: @maihabunash Then the solution to devnull would be better.

Comment: nearly, report80whatever.txt is also taken, ... @maihabunash, define a bit more the scope of file name convention to select so both the 2 reply could be adapted.